# How can I run through a range of numbers and look for numbers included in an array?

Tags: arrays, perl, iteration

I am trying to make a simple Perl script to take a range of numbers (`0..255`), run through each number and find the numbers that are NOT in another array.

The point of this so I can find which Minecraft block ids are not yet occupied in my game. The first array is a range `0..255` which is the max possible block ids. The next array is the already used ids that have made a list out of.

So I want some kind of loop that checks every possible block id. I will post what I have when get to my computer.

Comment: I have tried using each of the ideas but they all give the same result. They give me just a count of all number 0 - 255 which is wrong. I will try to fix my question to better focus on what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest (and fastest) way is transform the other array to a hash, and check for existence of keys there:

```
my %hash = map { $_ => 0 } @array2;

print (exists $hash{$_} ? "$_ is there\n" : "$_ is not there\n") for(0..255);
```

Comment: Oh! I never even thought of that. Nice I will give it a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use

```
$occupied_lookup[$_] = 1 for 4,5,6;
```

instead of

```
@occupied_indexes = (4,5,6);
```

Easier and faster to make something occupied:

```
$occupied_lookup[$_] = 1;
```

Easier and faster to make something unoccupied:

```
$occupied_lookup[$_] = 0;
```

Easier and faster to check if something is occupied:

```
if ($occupied_lookup[$_])
```

Finding all occupied index is still easy:

```
my @occupied_indexes = grep $occupied_lookup[$_], 0..$#occupied_lookup;
```

(Others have suggested a hash, but an array is faster.)

Answer (score 0):

Difference between two arrays doesn't necessarily mean you need a for loop or while, etc. This prints the items in @allblocks that are not in @occupiedones.

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
my @allblocks=(0...255);
my @occupiedones=(1,2,80,255)

my %occupiedones=map{$_=>1} @occupiedones;

# the difference of two arrays

my @diff=grep(!defined $occupiedones{$_}, @allblocks);

# proof it works
print "This is in one array and not the other:\t$_\n" foreach (@diff);
```

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want.  Comments in the code explain.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

# Print members of @b that are not in @a.
# That is, loosely speaking, print @b minus @a.

my @a = (10, 20, 30, 40, 50);
my @b = (22, 25, 30, 40, 42);

my %a = map {$_=>1} @a;
$a{$_} or print "$_ " for @b;
print "\n";
```

The idea is to turn `@a` into the hash `%a`, and then to use the hash to control the subtraction.  In the hash, only the keys are of interest; the corresponding values are all just `1`, which is conventional for this kind of application (the dummy value is Perl's way to implement what in C++ would be called a *set*).